# Design Bug: Horizontal Rule extends too far right

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See obligatory hand-drawn red circle in picture.

Chrome, Windows.

> [image]

Edited to add:
I assume this truncation is the same problem:

> [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I assume this is the [question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/do-women-prefer-taller-men) in your screenshot?

Comment: I am not able to replicate this on any machine here. ?

Answer (score 1):

this has been fixed. thanks for all the fancy red circles.

Comment: Not fixed on my machine, but I think I see the problem...

One of my plugins is adding the "history" link (just to the right of timeline), which is expanding that box enough to push the users names to the right and into the flow of traffic in the right-hand column.

Haven't yet tested turning off that plug-in - will do soon - but that's likely the problem.

The plugin is a popular one (will have to find its official name), but I don't know what policy is when a plugin mucks up the design.

Comment: this hasn't been built deployed. all of these fixes are on our dev servers.

Comment: Still a problem on my machine (with the userscript "SE Modifications")